# Unexpected bound error on Generics with two generics

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

In essence I want to create a structure of interfaces and classes where at different levels I want to force a certain type. In the example below I define an interface called `Engine` and `Body`. I want all `Car` classes to consist of a `Body` and `Engine`. However before I get to a specific Car class such as `MySportCar` I want to create subtypes of cars such as `SportCar` where a `SportCar` has to have a `V6` engine how any kind of `Body`. However when I try to do this I get an unexpected bound error. My code is:

```
public interface Body {
    int getNumberOfDoors();
}

public class Sedan implements Body {
    @Override
    public int getNumberOfDoors() {
        return 4;
    }
}

public interface Engine {
    int getHorsePower();
}

public class V6 implements Engine{
    @Override
    public int getHorsePower() {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

I then create the `Car` abstract class:

```
public class Car <B extends Body, E extends Engine>{

    private B body;
    private E engine;

    public Car(B body, E engine) {
        this.body = body;
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public B getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public E getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
}
```

Ideally I want something like this for the `SportCar` but it fails with the unbounded error:

```
public class SportCar extends Car<B extends Body, V6>{
    public SportCar(B body, V6 engine) {
        super(body, engine);
    }
}
```

And of course later I would create my own `SportCar`

```
public class MySportCar extends SportCar<Sedan, V6>{
    public MySportCar(Sedan body, V6 engine) {
        super(body, engine);
    }
}
```

But for now the issue is that the compiler doesn't like my class definition for the `SportCar`. Specifically the code `B extends Body` which results in an unexpected bound error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### #Solution

I think this is what you need...

```java
// Change is here
class SportCar<B extends Body, V extends V6> extends Car<B, V> {
    public SportCar (B body, V6 engine) {
        super (body, engine);
    }
}
// No change here
class MySportCar extends SportCar<Sedan, V6> {
    public MySportCar (Sedan body, V6 engine) {
        super (body, engine);
    }
}
```

The mistake here

```java
class SportCar extends Car<B extends Body, V6> {
```

is that you are using `B` type without declaring it. You have an undeclared generic type and you must first declare it using

```java
class SportCar<B extends Body, V extends V6> extends Car<B, V> {
// No error here
```

I presume you want `SportCar` to only allow `Body` and `V6` subs. and those are also the bounds of `Car` since it takes `Body` and `Engine` and `V6` implements engine.
So if my presumption is correct, you want to bound `SportCar` to only allow subs of `Body` and `V6`, then you arevgood to go...

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I actually had to also cast the engine in the constructor. That is super(body, (E)engine); for it to work. But that works for me. I would edit the answer and accept it but just in case you would prefer another resolution please go ahead and once it's updated I'll mark it as the answer. Again thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. But actually it's still off a bit. I need the SportCar to not have V extends V6 but just be V6. If I try to do that then it cannot resolve the engine V symbol in Car<B, V>. I ended up with: 

`public class SportCar<B extends Body, V6> extends Car<B, Engine>{
    public SportCar(B body, V6 engine) {
        super(body, (Engine)engine);
    }
}`

Comment: Actually change that. I ended up with a slightly different solution. I ended up with `SportCar<B extends Body> extends Car<B, V6>`. Anyways your solution helped me understand the issue so I'm marking it as the answer. Hopefully if someone needs more details they can also read the comments. Thank you.